# Could not execute query in spring boot framework

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

```
SELECT * FROM work_hour where start_time between '2020-04-06 23:03' and '2020-04-09 23:03';
```

This works when set search_path to foo
But Ii want to use the same query instead of strings I want to use parameters

So i'm using this annotation in my service function:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s FROM foo.work_hour s WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(s.start_time,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi')\\:\\:timestamp BETWEEN :start_time\\:\\:timestamp AND now()\\:\\:timestamp", nativeQuery = true)
```

But this seems to not work.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). could not execute query; SQL [SELECT s FROM logines.work_hour s WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(s.start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi')::timestamp BETWEEN ?::timestamp AND now()::timestamp]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.
```

How it can be done?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: `to_timestamp()` is used to convert something that is **not** a timestamp **to** a timestamp. Calling it on a column that **is** already a timestamp is completely wrong. I think you should replace `:start_time\\:\\:timestamp` with simply `:start_time`  and then pass an instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` as the parameter (or at least `java.sql.Timestamp`).

Comment: Have you tried to actually search what the error message means?

Answer (score 0):

As that is a native query, you need to use proper (native) SQL syntax.

```
select s from work_hour s
```

results in a result that has a **single** column which is a record with multiple fields. But you want multiple columns, so you have to use

```
select s.* 
from work_hour s
```

See the difference in the output in this [online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bf49f984ffcab7ae785d4ca00efc6a1e)